# Are "literally" and "metaphorically" synonymous?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I sometimes hear people speak and they sometimes say "literally" or "metaphorically"... are these words synonymous?

Comment: Yes, on occasion.

Comment: This being a text-only medium, I suppose I could say I'm literally speechless! ***And*** metaphorically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [literally as a hyperbole](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11065/literally-as-a-hyperbole) ('he was literally as big as a house' ... Is this actually ... incorrect or can the word 'literally' be a hyperbole strengthening a metaphor?) Though nohat's answer at ['literally' and 'decimate' misuse?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/literally-and-decimate-misuse) is excellent.

Comment: Strictly speaking, they are antonymous - but see the above comments on _literally_.

Comment: I abhor the figurative or hyperbolic use of "literally" as cited above, and generally regard speakers who use it this way to be ignorant of either its meaning or their own intent.