# History of "literally": Who changed the definition of "literally" to no longer mean "figuratively" in the first place?

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english, history, early-modern-english

According to my research, "literally" used to mean "figuratively", or at least it was used by many people to mean "figuratively" several centuries ago. Yet, although there were some detractors, I can't place where or who officially separated "literally" and "figuratively" to how we understood it in the past few decades, and I'd like to know how it all came about.

Comment: Did you come across this during your research? [Did We Change the Definition of 'Literally'?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/misuse-of-literally) (Merriam-Webster) TLDR; Dictionaries document usage. They don't invent meanings for words.

Comment: I see a form of inflation, or addiction to drama. When naughty wasn't enough to mean saucy but good, we needed bad and wicked. When figuratively or *really* lost their punch, literally took over. Literally. Meaning figuratively, but strongly so.

Comment: Please give a source for your research. Also be aware that English language usage is not changed by official decree — there is no equivalent of the Académie Française — but by usage.  Buy yourself a subscription to the OED to find the history of the usage of English words.

Comment: What do you mean by 'how we understood it in the past few decades'? The _proper_ meaning of 'literally' is 'in the literal sense of the word', but it is often used inaccurately  as a way of emphasising a figure of speech. As the Merriam-Webster article shows, English writers have been doing this for centuries, so it isn't a modern error.

Comment: @Steven Please **show** your research: exactly what you found, and where you found it.

Comment: Multiple similar questions have already been closed as duplicates of this: ["Literally" and "Decimate" misuse](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/literally-and-decimate-misuse) I don't think there's any more to be usefully added.

Comment: @David -  _Académie française_. Adjectives of nationality are not capitalised in French.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey — In fact I know that — I blame the computer. Actually I spend a lot of time changing the capitalization of French on ripped CDs or in the titles on my film library. The French are not always consistent in book titles etc., but I suppose the Académie française would get it right. (Although the last is penned with some trepidation)

Comment: @David I do this too with my ripped titles, films and music, even though only my wife and I will see them (she is a linguist). How sad is that? Also I am that rare thing in England, a fan of Indochine (the rock group). Allez Nicola !

Answer (score 3):

Your research, which you have not told us about, but should have done, is wrong because of a lack of research:

The simplest way to find the origins of a word and its history is [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=literally)

A better way is to gain access to the Oxford English Dictionary, which, for **literally**, gives:

> **1. a. In a literal, exact, or actual sense; not figuratively, allegorically, etc.**
>
> c1429   Mirour Mans Saluacioune (1986) l. 553   *Litteraly haf ȝe herde this dreme and what it ment.* [Literally you have heard this dream and what it meant.]

So we see that this is the earliest meaning and *literally* still has that meaning today.

But a few lines down, we have:

> **1. c.** colloquial. **Used to indicate that some (frequently conventional) metaphorical or hyperbolical expression is to be taken in the strongest admissible sense: ‘virtually, as good as’; (also) ‘completely, utterly, absolutely’.**
>
> *Now one of the most common uses, although often considered irregular in standard English since it reverses the original sense of literally (‘not figuratively or metaphorically’).*

The earliest record of this sense is

> 1769   F. Brooke Hist. Emily Montague IV. ccxvii. 83   *He is a fortunate man to be introduced to such a party of fine women at his arrival; it is literally to feed among the lilies.*

Both meanings exist side by side in current English. You should be able to tell which is which by the context.

> I can't place where or who officially separated "literally" and "figuratively".

And you never will be able to. English has no "official body" that says how the language may be used or what a word may mean.

Dictionaries are merely a record of the [almost] present meaning

Comment: The above gives the impression that all blockquotes are from Etymon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - a careful reader would disagree... :)

Comment: Not true. '1769 F. Brooke Hist. Emily Montague IV. ccxvii. 83 He is a fortunate man to be introduced to such a party of fine women at his arrival; it is literally to feed among the lilies.' could be a quote-within-a-quote.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sir, I say pish and poh to your cavils: regardless, in *to be introduced to such a party of fine women at his arrival; it is literally to feed among the lilies,* nobody fed and nobody was *among the lillies*."